# Save xlsx file with javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

Is it possible to write som cell data and save it as xlsx file on specific location on user drive with javascript?

you running the script locally to have write access.

Like PHPExcel where you use: $objWriter->save('/path/to/save/filename.extension');

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple libraries available to write,

http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xlsx/

https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

Comment: Hi Ravindra. Thanks for providing an answer, but if you could also provide some code and/or copy and paste the relevant info from the links, or both...? At the moment this would be termed a link only answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers . If you add more info it's more likely to be useful to people browsing the site, and hence more likely to get upvotes and less likely to be closed.